# how to draw pixel perfect line chart

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I used Flutter's canvas.drawLine to draw a line chart.
However, you can see every single line if you zoom in, which looks bad.

[image]

The same is true when using canvas.drawPoints.

The only solution left seems to draw a custom path. However, I'm really struggling to do this.

Do you have any suggestions to draw a pixel perfect line chart?

(I can't use any charting libraries like fl_chart.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Path.lineTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/lineTo.html) instead, the [StrokeJoin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeJoin.html) says that joining lines is only available for a path.

```dart
class PaintChart extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> points;
  const PaintChart(this.points);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final bounds = Offset.zero & size;

    final path = Path();
    final paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 8
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;

    canvas.drawRect(
      Offset.zero & size,
      Paint()..color = Colors.blueAccent,
    );

    path.moveTo(0, bounds.height / 2);
    
    for (final point in points) {
      path.lineTo(
        point.dx,
        point.dy + bounds.height / 2,
      );
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PaintChart old) => false;
}
```

And to test it in the pad.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({super.key});

  final points = List<Offset>.generate(24, (i) {
    return Offset(i.toDouble() * 25, sin(i) * 50);
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: PaintChart(points),
                ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This example is the same as the other one but interactive and with colors, essentially, if you want to keep the lines contiguous and paint them you can use the path as a mask for a shader or you can overlay segments of the same path with different paints.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _App();
}

class _App extends State<App> {
  double amplitude = 40;
  double frequency = 40;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text('Amplitude'),
                  Slider(
                    min: 20,
                    max: 200,
                    value: amplitude,
                    label: amplitude.round().toString(),
                    onChanged: (double value) => setState(
                      () => amplitude = value,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text('Frequency'),
                  Slider(
                    min: 10,
                    max: 200,
                    value: frequency,
                    label: frequency.round().toString(),
                    onChanged: (double value) => setState(
                      () => frequency = value,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              WavePlot(
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                points: List<Offset>.generate(1000, (i) {
                  return Offset(
                    i.toDouble(),
                    amplitude * sin(i / frequency),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WavePlot extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;

  // The points are in Cartesian and the values should be
  // scaled here because the size of the WavePlot is now known
  final List<Offset> points;

  const WavePlot({
    super.key,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.points,
  });

  @override
  State<WavePlot> createState() => _WavePlot();
}

class _WavePlot extends State<WavePlot> {
  double selection_lo = 0.2;
  double selection_hi = 0.8;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: widget.width,
          height: widget.height,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: PaintWavePlot(
              widget.points,
              selection_lo,
              selection_hi,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          // 50 is just a random padding offset, the
          // correct values is in the [Theme] somewhere
          width: widget.width + 50,
          child: RangeSlider(
            values: RangeValues(
              selection_lo,
              selection_hi,
            ),
            onChanged: (values) {
              setState(() {
                selection_lo = values.start;
                selection_hi = values.end;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PaintWavePlot extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> points;
  final double selection_lo;
  final double selection_hi;

  const PaintWavePlot(
    this.points,
    this.selection_lo,
    this.selection_hi,
  );

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final bounds = Offset.zero & size;

    // Painting only needs to be done in the line
    canvas.saveLayer(bounds, Paint());

    // The path line is a mask for the other layers

    final line_path = Path();
    line_path.moveTo(0, bounds.height / 2);

    for (final point in points) {
      line_path.lineTo(
        point.dx,
        point.dy + bounds.height / 2,
      );
    }

    canvas.drawPath(
      line_path,
      Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 8
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round,
    );

    canvas.drawRect(
      bounds,
      Paint()
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn
        ..shader = const LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: <Color>[
            Colors.green,
            Colors.greenAccent,
            Colors.redAccent,
            Colors.red,
          ],
          stops: [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
        ).createShader(bounds),
    );

    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromLTRB(
        size.width * selection_lo,
        0,
        size.width * selection_hi,
        size.height,
      ),
      Paint()
        ..color = Colors.blue
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn,
    );

    // Apply the blended drawings to the screen
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawRect(
      bounds,
      Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 6
        ..color = Colors.black87
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round,
    );

    final plot_paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..color = Colors.black87
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(0, bounds.height / 2),
      Offset(bounds.width, bounds.height / 2),
      plot_paint,
    );

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(bounds.width * selection_lo, 0),
      Offset(bounds.width * selection_lo, bounds.height),
      plot_paint,
    );
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(bounds.width * selection_hi, 0),
      Offset(bounds.width * selection_hi, bounds.height),
      plot_paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PaintWavePlot old) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great.
I need to color parts of the path in a different color. I could draw the path a second time in a different color over the first path. Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: That would be a way to do it but depending on how you want to make it look, you might end up using a mask with overlapped paths, so it's up to you to decide what is the  'simpler solution'.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my source code here https://github.com/duytq94/flutter-custom-line-chart

[image]

If you have any questions, put them here or open issues in the repo are fine.